# Access VM at the lowest power state possible

Tags: networking, suspend

I'm trying to access a VM remotely is the lowest power state possible.

I realise if the system is suspended, then that's just not possible (due to the nature of suspend), but it's the case that even just going to sleep the connection is severed.

Is there a state that I can employ that allows running processes (or at least particular processes for the purpose of networking and the VM) so that I may still SSH into the VM or access it's web portal?

Comment: The VM guest is Ubuntu? Which Ubuntu?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long would be kinda depends on what you are actually asking. ACPI defines the following power states: S0 Working, S1 Power on Suspend, S2 CPU off, S3 Standby, S4 Hibernate and S5 Soft Off (some devices are powered to maintain functionality of the computer such as the power button or even Wake On Lan.) In none of these states besides S0 is the CPU functional. There is some specialized hardware like Killer NIC cards that have a processor on the NIC. Still not sure if thats what you're expecting at all.